# catkin make error

Tags: catkin, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I input catkin_make,then output:

```
CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
/home/jeff/dev/myros1/src/example1/CMakeLists.txt:29:
Parse error.  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/jeff/dev/myros1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/jeff/dev/myros1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

but the txt in my `CMakeLists.txt:29` file is:

```
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
```

I don't why.please help me! I will appreciate it!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228856/catkin-make-error/) by [wjch](https://answers.ros.org/users/26234/wjch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The lines,

```
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
```

belong in the `package.xml` file. The way you include `roscpp` in your `CMakeLists.txt` file is with the following:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
)
```

Look at the ROS wiki pages on [CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) and [package.xml](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml) for more guidelines.

If you still need more help it would be useful to post your CMakeLists.txt and package.xml files so that we can see what is wrong with them.

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2016-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wjch](https://answers.ros.org/users/26234/wjch/) on 2016-03-12**:
Thanks for your attention, so,as you said ,I have added "find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)" into the txt,but it's the same error,help me please!

**Comment by [wjch](https://answers.ros.org/users/26234/wjch/) on 2016-03-12**:
this is my txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(exam1)

### Find catkin macros and libraries

##if COMPONENTS list like
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)

### is used, also find other catkin packages

##find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

### System dependencies are found with CMak

**Comment by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) on 2016-03-13**:
Did you also remove the lines <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend> and <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend> from CMakeLists.txt, and put them in package.xml?

**Comment by [wjch](https://answers.ros.org/users/26234/wjch/) on 2016-03-14**:
yes,I do as what you have said,and now I have solved and it works now!thank you

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-14**:
Please check the answer as accepted.